# Removing leading digits from number scanned into google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have made a spreadsheet that is used as a repair log for my company , bar codes are scanned into it. The bar code is 20 digits long however i only want to record the last 10 digits.

I have tried custom number formatting but cant seem to get anything to work.

this is an example of the bar code "1P000000001770039735"

the first 10 digits are always the same so i dont need to record them but the last 10 digits are always different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

run a script with

```
str.slice(10,19)
```

Answer (score 0):

With data in **A1**, in **B1** enter:

```
=MID(A1,11,10)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i need the barcode to stay in the original cell it was scanned into and not an adjacent cell

Comment: Here is the spreadsheet, https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18JmMzvaP-2_Z7zx8VezCPqjJlTQd-Vy1m8-kFw-t4pA/edit?usp=sharing , you can see how i am using the bar code

Answer (score 0):

Thanks people, this is how i did it..........

i scan in 3 different bar codes and the code takes off the right amount of digits from the start of each one.

if anyone thinks i can simplify it please let me know

```
function Barcode(){
var RepairLog = ss.getSheetByName("Repair Log");
var RepairLogLastRow = RepairLog.getLastRow();
var RICObarcoderange = RepairLog.getRange(RepairLogLastRow, 4);
var PNbarcoderange = RepairLog.getRange(RepairLogLastRow, 5);
var DELNOTEbarcoderange = RepairLog.getRange(RepairLogLastRow, 2);

var DELNOTEbarcode = DELNOTEbarcoderange.getValue();
var RICObarcode = RICObarcoderange.getValue();
var PNbarcode = PNbarcoderange.getValue();

var rico = RICObarcode.slice(2,12);
var pn = PNbarcode.slice(10,20);
var delnote = DELNOTEbarcode.slice(5,21);

if (PNbarcode.length > 10)
{PNbarcoderange.setValue(pn)}

if (DELNOTEbarcode.length > 18)
{DELNOTEbarcoderange.setValue(delnote)}

if (RICObarcode.length > 10)
{RICObarcoderange.setValue(rico)}

return null

}
```